Secure Boot is toggled off, even though an UEFI install was used and secure boot is enabled in BIOS
I was wondering why my secure boot in Windows is still disabled, even though my NVMe main disk was installed with UEFI? I need secure boot to launch Valorant's anticheat software. With WhyNotWin11:

Secure boot is disabled, and this can be seen in msinfo32:

Secure boot - off. However, in BIOS, the CSM is turned off, and secure boot is set to UEFI.


My hard drive even has an EFI partition, so this has to indicate it is in UEFI.

Furthermore, the hard drive is in GPT mode:

One week ago, I had a problem that my hard drive (NVMe) containing Windows would not start without my original SSD; I used the manual from this question (Booting Windows off M.2 NVMe doesn’t work even though it is recognized by the BIOS on a dual boot machine) to install an Windows Boot Loader; is that the problem? Because the installation was not perfect from the get-go?
Using regedit, I can set the secure boot to “1”, but this will get lost on a new start-up.
Maybe you have some advice. Reinstalling Windows, in the sense that I would lose my files, is out of the question as it is my work PC.

UEFI, UEFI mode and Secure Boot are different things. You can have an installation in UEFI mode with Secure Boot enabled or disabled. Indeed, Secure Boot is immaterial if you enable CSM ("Legacy" AKA "BIOS" mode) because it's a setting exclusive to UEFI. You need to check other settings. Please read your user's manual.

You need to Setup Secure Boot within the UEFI settings. Reinstalling Windows wouldn’t solve your problem

How can I do that? Setup secure boot within uefi?

If you mean UEFI BIOS, that’s what I did as you can see in the pictures or did you mean something else?
